# C++ How to make a function return the object that called it?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This feels like it should be obvious but I have looked for a while and must not be asking the question right. I am doing an assignment operator overload for a Vector2D class. The function just converts the calling object's x and y coordinates to the vector passed in the argument:

```
// Vector2D.h
class Vector2D
{
public:

    float x, y;

    Vector2D();
    Vector2D(float x, float y);
.
.
.
Vector2D& operator=(const Vector2D& vec);
.
.
.
}
```

and

```
// Vector2D.cpp
.
.
.
Vector2D & Vector2D::operator=(const Vector2D & vec)
{
    this->x = vec.x;
    this->y = vec.y;
    return ? ? ? ? ;
}
.
.
.
```

What am I supposed to return to make this work? I naively thought `return this;` would do it but that is not the proper reference.

Comment: `return *this;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I naively thought `return this;` would do it but that does not the proper reference.

`this` is a **pointer** to the current object. To achieve your desired result, simply dereference it: `*this`.

Comment: ugh. Thanks, I feel like I wasted your time. I have been up all night solving much harder problems, I swear!

Comment: @hatinacat2000 • I think most C++ programmers when first learning C++ make that mistake.  The reason `this` is a self-referencing pointer rather than a self-referencing reference is because references hadn't been added to the C++ language yet when it was first being created.

Comment: @hatinacat2000 Please accept the answer if it helped you to solve your problem.